# Error in BASH : oauth_listener() needs an interactive environment

Tags: r, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-apps

I'm trying to run some Rscript via cron job.
I am using RGA package. 
The error I get in terminal is:

> Access token will be stored in the './ga-token.rds' file.
>   Error:
>   oauth_listener() needs an interactive environment.
>
> Execution halted

My code is:

```
library(RGA)

authorize(client.id = ".......", client.secret = ".......", cache = "./ga-token.rds")
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to download and install httpuv
install.packages ("httpuv").
after that
require("httpuv").
It's working:
rga_auth <- authorize(client.id = "XXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com", client.secret = "XXXXXXXXXX")
Access token will be stored in the '.ga-token.rds' file.
Adding .ga-token.rds to .gitignore
Waiting for authentication in browser...
Press Esc/Ctrl + C to abort
Authentication complete.